# Запрос для нахождения схожих записей

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица, 5000 строк:

```
id name
```

Как мне реализовать запрос для нахождение id, name-ы которых идентичны.
P.S. предварительно я не знаю, что искать.
Если можно короткую инструкцию, пжл.

Comment: join таблицы с самой собой по условию равенства name и разных id

Comment: Вот даже просто перевести хотелку на аглицкий - и уже достаточно для получения ответа. `WHERE t1.name = t2.name AND t1.id != t2.id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дано:

```
id | name
----------
1  | test1
2  | test2
3  | test1
4  | test4
5  | test4
6  | test1
```

Есть несколько вариантов решения, Вы выберите какой больше нравится:

**Первый:**

Как и сказали в комментариях - через JOIN таблицы самой в себя:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   t1.id AS some_id
FROM table t1 JOIN table t2 ON t1.name = t2.name AND t1.id != t2.id
```

Результат:

```
some_id
-------
1
4
```

Note: стоит сказать, что сортированный вывод связан с особенностью работы `DISTINCT` в PostgreSQL (MySQL под рукой нету),  который перед тем как исключить повторения сортирует таблицу.

Без `DISTINCT` будет:

```
some_id
-------
1
3
6
4
5
```

**Второй** вариант, если нужно отсечь точное количество повторений - подзапрос:

```
SELECT
   table.id AS some_id
FROM
   (SELECT
       name,
       count(id) AS c
    FROM
       table
    GROUP BY name) AS sub_data JOIN table ON table.name = data.name
WHERE
   c = 2
```

Результат:

```
some_id
-------
4
5
```

Comment: `having count(id) > 1` обычно пишут в таких случаях

Comment: @teran я или что-то не так делал, или из-за особенностей постгреса у меня не получилось, можете написать запрос?

Comment: `select name from t group by name having count(id) > 1` и не надо `c=2` будет. а вместо джойна можно `where name in (...)` сделать